# How to transform a 2d array in to two different 1d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm trying to transform one 2d array:

```
{4: 6, 6: 2, 1: 2, 3: 7, 5: 4, 9: 1, 2: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1}
```

in to 2 different 1d arrays, like this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
arr2 = [2, 3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

To plot, using matplotlib, arr1 as y and arr2 as x.

How can I do this?

PS: Sorry for the bad English. (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
d = {4: 6, 6: 2, 1: 2, 3: 7, 5: 4, 9: 1, 2: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1}
sorted_list = sorted(d.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
x, y = zip(*sorted_list) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

output :

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
d = {4: 6, 6: 2, 1: 2, 3: 7, 5: 4, 9: 1, 2: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1}

arr1, arr2 = map(list, zip(*d.items()))
```

output:

```
arr1
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

arr2
# [2, 3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

A convenience, if you want to plot, might be to use [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(d).sort_index().plot()

# or
# import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
# plt.plot(pd.Series(d).sort_index())
```

output:

[image]